# Sort a list by property and add an object before each first letter changes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I am trying to make a UI like this:

[image]

And I have an array of users

```
[{name: 'Julia'}, {name: 'Ismeh'}, {name: 'Alison'}, {name: 'Andrea'}, {name: 'Betty'}]
```

What I am trying to do is to sort the array by first letter of the name property, and add a header object before each. For example in the picture, you can see the letter A, B, I, and J as the headers.

For now, I got it working like this:

```
    let final = []
    // sort by first letter
    const sortedUsers = state.test_list.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
    for (let x = 0; x < sortedUsers.length; x++) {
        const user = sortedUsers[x].name
        if (user.charAt(0) === 'A') {
            const checkIfExists = final.findIndex((f) => f.header === 'A')
            // add the header A if it doesn't exist
            if (checkIfExists < 0) final.push({header: 'A'})
        }
        else if (user.charAt(0) === 'B') {
            const checkIfExists = final.findIndex((f) => f.header === 'B')
            // add the header B if it doesn't exist
            if (checkIfExists < 0) final.push({header: 'B'})
        }
        // else if up to the letter Z
        final.push(user)
    }
```

and if I log the final array, I get:

[image]

which is correct.

My concern is that the code is very long, and I have no idea if it can be optimized or make the code smaller. Is there any other option to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough, try sorting them and then using `.reduce`:

```js
const unsortedPeople = [{name: 'Julia'}, {name: 'Ismeh'}, {name: 'Alison'}, {name: 'Andrea'}, {name: 'Betty'}];
const sortedUsers = unsortedPeople.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
const final = sortedUsers.reduce((finalSoFar, user) => {
  const thisUserFirstChar = user.name[0];
  if (finalSoFar.length === 0) addHeader();
  else {
    const lastUserFirstChar = finalSoFar[finalSoFar.length - 1].name[0];
    if (lastUserFirstChar !== thisUserFirstChar) addHeader();
  }
  finalSoFar.push(user);
  return finalSoFar;
  function addHeader() {
    finalSoFar.push({ header: thisUserFirstChar });
  }
}, []);

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you create a collection of names, which is grouped by the first letter? You can then loop on it, and create your list. Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create the grouped collection.

And then use [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate over the grouped collection and render your results:

```js
let data = [{
  name: 'Julia'
}, {
  name: 'Ismeh'
}, {
  name: 'Alison'
}, {
  name: 'Andrea'
}, {
  name: 'Betty'
}];

let combined = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  let letter = item.name[0].toUpperCase();
  if (!result[letter]) {
    result[letter] = [];
  }

  result[letter].push(item);
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(combined);

// Iterate over the result
Object.keys(combined).forEach(key => {
  // key will be the first letter of the user names and
  // combined[key] will be an array of user objects
  console.log(key, combined[key]);
});
```

One thing still to do is to sort the user arrays by user name, which you can do easily using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: Awesome! This is something what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just keep track of the current abbreviation as you loop. Then you can add a head when it changes:

```js
var users = [{name: 'Julia'}, {name: 'Ismeh'}, {name: 'Alison'}, {name: 'Andrea'}, {name: 'Betty'}]

const sortedUsers = users.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
var currentHeader 
let final = sortedUsers.reduce((a, user) => {
    if (currentHeader !==  user.name[0]) {
        currentHeader = user.name[0]
        a.push({header: currentHeader})
    }
    a.push(user)
    return a
},[])

console.log(final)
```

Comment: This looks awesome too. I will also try this out

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
const users = [{name: 'Julia'}, {name: 'Ismeh'}, {name: 'Alison'}, {name: 'Andrea'}, {name: 'Betty'}];

let lastIndex;
let result = [];
users.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.name > b.name;
}).forEach((user) => {
  const index = user.name.charAt(0);
  if (index !== lastIndex) {
    result.push({
      header: index
    });
  }
  lastIndex = index;
  result.push(user.name);
}, []);






console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`_.orderBy(collection, [iteratees=[_.identity]], [orders])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#orderBy) and [`_.groupBy(collection, [iteratee=_.identity])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy) method of lodash.

- This **orderBy** is like _.sortBy except that it allows specifying the sort orders of the iteratees to sort by. If orders is unspecified, all values are sorted in ascending order. Otherwise, specify an order of "desc" for descending or "asc" for ascending sort order of corresponding values.
- **groupBy** will creates an object composed of keys generated from the results of running each element of collection thru iteratee. The order of grouped values is determined by the order they occur in collection. The corresponding value of each key is an array of elements responsible for generating the key. The iteratee is invoked with one argument: (value).

example

```
// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.groupBy(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'length');
// => { '3': ['one', 'two'], '5': ['three'] }

// Sort by `user` in ascending order and by `age` in descending order.
_.orderBy(users, ['user', 'age'], ['asc', 'desc']);
```

> With lodash

```js
let myArr = [{
  name: 'Julia'
}, {
  name: 'Ismeh'
}, {
  name: 'Andrea'
}, {
  name: 'Alison'
}, {
  name: 'Betty'
}];

myArr = _.orderBy(myArr, ['name'], ['asc']);

let r = _.groupBy(myArr, o => {
  return o.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
})

console.log(r);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

> IN ES5

```js
var arr = [{
    name: 'Julia'
  }, {
    name: 'Ismeh'
  }, {
    name: 'Andrea'
  }, {
    name: 'Alison'
  }, {
    name: 'Betty'
  }],
  fChar = '';
  
  
arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  a = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  b = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
}).reduce(function(r, o) {
  fChar = o.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  if (!r[fChar]) {
    r[fChar] = [];
  }
  r[fChar].push({
    name: o.name
  });
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(arr);
```

> IN ES6

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'Julia'
}, {
    name: 'Ismeh'
}, {
    name: 'Andrea'
}, {
    name: 'Alison'
}, {
    name: 'Betty'
}];

let result = arr.sort((a, b) => {
    a = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    b = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
}).reduce((r, o) => {
    let fChar = o.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    if (!r[fChar]) {
        r[fChar] = [];
    }
    r[fChar].push({
        name: o.name
    });
    return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```